# Why does width:0 not animate (anime.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, anime.js

I am trying to create an animation with the width of an element, but even this basic code doesn't work and I can't figure out why, maybe someone can.

```html
<script src="anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div id="centered">
</div>

<style>
  #centered {
    width: 500px;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: blueviolet;
  }
</style>

<script>
let t = anime.timeline({
  target: '#centered',
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  width: 0,
  duration: 1000,
});

t.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors? If so what are they? Be more precise than "doesn't work".

Comment: Sadly there are no console errors, only the "complete" code from the animation works

Comment: Is anime.min.js correct as path for the file?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'target' should be `targets` (plural). Following documentation, you should be adding (what I would call) keyframes via `.add` according to the [timeline basics](https://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineBasics). Not certain if you need it explicitly.

```js
let t = anime.timeline({
  targets: '#centered',
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false
});

t.add({ width: 0, duration: 1000 });

t.play();
```

```css
#centered {
    width: 27px;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: blueviolet;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="centered">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following solutions?

Example 1 (With timeline)

```
var t = anime.timeline({
  duration: 1000,
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
});

t.add({
  targets: '#centered',
  width: 0
})

t.play();
```

Example 2 (Without timeline)

```
var t = anime({
  duration: 1000,
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  targets: '#centered',
  width: 0
});

t.play();
```

For more information, it's better to check an official document.
https://animejs.com/documentation/